# Process (Java) is using 100% CPU , while my multithreaded application is running and my threads are in waiting condition

Tags: java, multithreading, macos

Process (Java) is using 100% CPU , while my multithreaded application is running and my threads are in waiting condition.

I have tried same application on a Windows based computer and its not a issue there, there cpu is used around 30%.

Application Details:

Consumer that implements Runnable

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        synchronized (vQueue) {
            vQueue.wait();
            e = (MyEvent) vQueue.poll();
        }
        if (e != null) {
            treatEvent(e);
        }
    }
}
```

code works fine..

my Question is more about the JVM performance difference on MAC, if it is.. then is there any way i can change the behaviour.

Comment: If code is the same, then there's an issue with either JVM or OSX thread implementation.

Comment: if you are calling wait then from where you are notifying??

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes, thats exactly my question is too,,, any one have experienced same, or some one know OSX thread implementation.

Comment: @Prashant i have a producer class. that puts the MyEvent in vQueue, and calls notifyAll();  that works fine,,, as new event added, its is consumed.,,and Thread goes to waiting state,,, tested the execution by putting sysouts...

Comment: I think you shouldn't reinvent the wheel, there are already threads pools implementations.

Comment: Why aren't you using the BlockingQueue's 'take' and 'put' methods? It does both - synchronization and wait/notify for you.